# JavaScript or PHP scripts to track image clicks and impressions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am looking for a PHP or JavaScript script to track the clicks and impressions on an image or link. I tried using http://www.phpjunkyard.com/ccount/admin/admin.php, but it can only track clicks. The problem is: this system creates a unique link with an id to track the clicks. Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a php where you want you client side to send you the click and impression notification.

*(javascript is a whole name of language so if you say a php script, say a javascript script, just to help).*

create a js script that send a request on the events onload and onclick on all img element of the page.

using jquery it'll be something like this:

```
//onclick event handler
$('img').on('click',function(){
    $.post('yourphpscript.php',{ path: $(this).attr('url'), event: "click" });
});
//onload event handler
$('img').on('load',function(){
    $.post('yourphpscript.php',{ path: $(this).attr('url'), event: "load" });
});
```

and then you create your php code that is waiting for a post request and does what ever you want.